# RoleDefinitions.BreakInheritance 2013 CSOM API

Tags: 2013, client-object-model

I need to break permission level inheritance.
The following works fine with the server API:

```
SPWeb.RoleDefinitions.BreakInheritance(true, true)
```

Now I need to do the same with Sharepoint 2013 CSOM API.
The method `BreakInheritance` seems not to be available for `RoleDefinitions`.

Answer (score 1):

Since SPRoleDefinitionCollection.BreakInheritance method creates unique role definitions for the **current Web site**, you could utilize the following method for that purpose in CSOM:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
     ctx.Web.BreakRoleInheritance(true, true);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: This breaks group inheritance only. It does not break the permission level inheritance :(

Comment: Hm, I'll take a look..